# Resharper 6 - automatically adding "this"

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

There is a naming style in a company I work for that "this" must be added to every function, property call and field. Sometimes I forget about it. I want Resharper to do it automatically.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Find option `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Other -> Other | Force "this." qualifier for instance member` and change it to `Use always`, then run full Code Cleanup.

Comment: For anyone in the future: In ReSharper 9, I had to change the setting in `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Code Style -> Use "this." qualifier for -> None`

Comment: For anyone in the future future: In ReSharper 2017.2, in addition to @EricHotinger comment i had to changed one more setting in `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Code Style -> Qualify members declared in -> None`

Comment: Further into the future (2020.1): ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Syntax Style -> Use "this." qualifier for -> None